# Additional Google Fonts on BigCommerce Stencil Theme

Tags: bigcommerce

How do I add additional Google Fonts to the stencil theme?

I see three choices: logo-font, body-font, and headings-font. I assigned a different Google font for each and they work perfectly. I am trying to add an additional font.

**ON CONFIG.JSON**
"font-custom1": "Google-Roboto+Condensed_700"

**ON CSS:**
p{font-family:  stencilFontFamily("font-custom1");}

On the paragraph tag, I can see the font-family became "Roboto Condensed". However, the font isn't Roboto Condensed on the browser.

Is there any other file that I need to tweak?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

put this in the `<head>`

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
```

**or**

this in an `.scss` file

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed');
```

I think there is a stencil way but it wasnt worth the trouble last time i tried.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to keep the consistent structure but guess that's not going to work.